Grouping of data based on patterns or sets of other rows
I have a data set with two columns (Person and Item) and I want to generate a group column (Group) based on column1 but the group will expand to include rows which have the same values as column 2.
Sample1 - because 1 and 2 both have a and b, they are considered 1 group. 3 is separated because it is the only one with item a.



Person
Item
Group




1
a
1


1
b
1


2
a
1


2
b
1


3
a
2



Sample2 - because 1 and 2 have different items, they are considered separate groups. 3 is also separate even though it has the same "a" item because it is the only item it has.



Person
Item
Group




1
a
1


1
b
1


2
c
2


2
d
2


3
a
3



Sample3 - both 1 and 2 have the same items so they are all considered as 1 group



Person
Item
Group




1
a
1


1
b
1


1
c
1


2
a
1


2
b
1


2
c
1



I found a similar post but this doesn't have the same grouping/checking mechanic on the second column:
Group identifiers/values that are related with each other between multiple columns
I'm thinking I need to do a self-join based on Item and loop through it, but a bit stuck as of the moment.
Thanks in advance!

Identify sets of items per person, then group by that sets.
with t (person, item) as (
select 1, 'a' union all
select 1, 'b' union all
select 2, 'a' union all
select 2, 'b' union all
select 3, 'a'
)
, person_to_itemset as (
select person, string_agg(item,',') within group (order by item) as itemset
from t
group by person
)
, itemset_to_group as (
select itemset, row_number() over (order by min(person)) grp
from person_to_itemset
group by itemset
)
select t.*, ig.grp
from t
join person_to_itemset pi on t.person = pi.person
join itemset_to_group ig on pi.itemset = ig.itemset





person
item
grp




1
a
1


1
b
1


2
a
1


2
b
1


3
a
2



fiddle
(Note that string_agg function was used just to demonstration purposes. To work safely the item column must not contain the comma character and probably it won't perform well on large number of items per person. Grouping directly into collection type could be alternative, unfortunately I actually don't use SQL Server and am not certain if it supports some collection, including ability to equality comparison for grouping, it is also important whether items per person form set or multiset.)

Please update question, the markdown in comments is unreadable. (Generally the best way to prepare sample data for [sql] question is to prepare fiddle rather than ascii tables. It helps to concentrate on answer instead of text formatting.)

Brillliant! This works great, thank you

Could just use dense_rank instead of the second join https://dbfiddle.uk/U7FNjAhQ note that this also allows the STRING_AGG to be optimized into an internal undocumented STRING_AGG OVER window function

Heh - was going to comment that his tags (SQL Server 2012) don't support STRING_AGG, but he says the answer works great! Secondly, note that I think if you can have duplicates (e.g., Person 1 linked to Item 'a' several times) then it will treat these as different from those with the same items but no duplicates.

I tried string_agg over on dbfiddle and didn't worked for me, I have otherwise no SQL Server available. And yes, with duplicates the behaviour differs, that's reason of my note about sets and multisets (string_agg is multiset comparison, string_agg(distinct item ...) would do set comparison but it does not work for me in SQL Server either - probably it would have to be emulated as subquery).
